# Check whether two files exist (in shell script)

Tags: file, shell

I'm writing a shell script and trying to check whether two files exists. 
Here is the script example:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ [ -e File1Name ] -a [ -e File2Name ] ]]
then
  echo Yes
el
  echo No
fi
```

and get

```
script: line 5: conditional binary operator expected
script: line 5: syntax error near `-e'
script: line 5: `if [[ [ -e CA ] -a [ -e CA-draw ] ]]'
```

What is wrong with my script and hot to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if [ -e File1Name -a -e File2Name ]
then
    echo Yes
else
    echo No
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Both `[[` and `[` are commands; you need to pick *one* of them, and use only it with `if`.